# How can I solve the ORA-01799 when creating a VIEW with a LEFT OUTER JOIN and a MAX value?

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create a view that joins a few tables, one of the joins is using a max value and I think that is generating the following error in our Oracle DB:
ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery.
Can anyone help me to change the estatement to create the view? The query works fine, the problem only comes when I try to create a view with it.

```
CREATE or replace VIEW xxxxxx_V (ID, SERVICE_ID, PARENT_ID, PARENT_MATERIALITY, PARENT_END_STATUS,
PARENT_OUTS_TYPE, END_STATUS, MATERIALITY, OUTS_TYPE, CREATED_BY,
SERVICE_DESCRIPTION_SHORT, VERSION, OUTSOURCER_ID, OUTSOURCER_NAME, INSOURCER_ID, INSOURCER_NAME, PLANNED_SERVICE_START) AS
select c.id id, s.id service_id, s.outsourcing_id parent_id, p.materiality parent_materiality, p.end_status parent_end_status,
p.outsourcing_type parent_outs_type, c.end_status end_status, c.materiality materiality, c.outsourcing_type outs_type, c.created_by created_by,
r.service_description_short, r.version, r.outsourcer outsourcer_id, o.name outsourcer_name , r.insourcer insourcer_id,i.name insourcer_name, r.planned_service_start
from OS_OUTSOURCING_CONTRACT c
left join OS_SERVICES s on s.id = c.service_id
left join OS_OUTSOURCING_CONTRACT p on p.id = s.outsourcing_id
left join OS_RISK_ASSESSMENT r on r.outsourcing_id = c.id and r.version = (select max(version) from OS_RISK_ASSESSMENT where outsourcing_id = c.id)
left join OS_COMPANY_INSOURCER i on i.id = r.insourcer
left join OS_COMPANY_OUTSOURCER o on o.id = r.outsourcer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the subquery into the query:

```
CREATE or replace VIEW xxxxxx_V
   (ID, SERVICE_ID, PARENT_ID, PARENT_MATERIALITY, PARENT_END_STATUS,
    PARENT_OUTS_TYPE, END_STATUS, MATERIALITY, OUTS_TYPE, CREATED_BY,
    SERVICE_DESCRIPTION_SHORT, VERSION, OUTSOURCER_ID, OUTSOURCER_NAME,
    INSOURCER_ID, INSOURCER_NAME, PLANNED_SERVICE_START) AS
select c.id,
       s.id service_id,
       s.outsourcing_id parent_id,
       p.materiality parent_materiality,
       p.end_status parent_end_status,
       p.outsourcing_type parent_outs_type,
       c.end_status,
       c.materiality,
       c.outsourcing_type outs_type,
       c.created_by,
       r.service_description_short,
       r.version,
       r.outsourcer outsourcer_id,
       o.name outsourcer_name,
       r.insourcer insourcer_id,
       i.name insourcer_name,
       r.planned_service_start
from OS_OUTSOURCING_CONTRACT c
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select outsourcing_id,
                        max(version) AS MAX_VERSION
                   from OS_RISK_ASSESSMENT
                   group by outsourcing_id) ora
  ON ora.OUTSOURCING_ID = c.id
left join OS_SERVICES s
  on s.id = c.service_id
left join OS_OUTSOURCING_CONTRACT p
  on p.id = s.outsourcing_id
left join OS_RISK_ASSESSMENT r
  on r.outsourcing_id = ora.OUTSOURCING_ID and
     r.version = ora.MAX_VERSION
left join OS_COMPANY_INSOURCER i
  on i.id = r.insourcer
left join OS_COMPANY_OUTSOURCER o
  on o.id = r.outsourcer
```

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your expertise with me, that has worked! I hope I can help you one day